# How to make factory in Doctrine 2 entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm

Exaple:

We have entity User. User have different parameters for different user types.
User type "admin", "manager", "customer" have own parameter set.

How i can make factory in entity User? I mean structure and function getTypeParams returns params of the user's type.

How i made:

Entity User have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10)
 */
private $type;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UserTypeAdmin", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="typeadmin_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $type_admin;
```

Entity UserTypeAdmin have parameterset for admin.

But problem is that entity User in db table have columns: typeadmin_id, typemanager_id, typecustomer_id... And one of these columns have value, but other columns equals null.

If user have one type, why we need making columns for every type: typeadmin_id, typemanager_id, typecustomer_id in user table?

Any way to do this beautifully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic issue is that you really can't have one property (type) point to multiple tables.  At least not very efficiently.  You would first have to query for the type then look up the table for that type and then do a second query to get the type entity.  Messy.

Fortunately, Doctrine 2 supports class table inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

You will want to make a base Type entity and then derive individual types (Admin, Manager etc) from it.  Do some configuration and you will end up with a nice one to one relation between the User entity and it's Type with each type having it's own distinct set of attributes.